# SmartSheet API python extended object

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

There are several objects in the SmartSheet SDK API which are extensions of objects. For instance, CellLink and ObjectValue are an extensions of the Cell object. I've done some reading and understand that these are parent/child classes and involve inheritance. However, this concept still escapes me and I cannot figure out the syntax for creating a CellLink object.

```
new_cell = ss.models.Cell()
linked_cell = ss.models.Cell()
linked_cell.column_id = int(columnid)
linked_cell.sheet_id = int(sheetid)
linked_cell.row_id = int(rowid)
new_cell.link_in_from_cell = linked_cell
```

The example above gives me the most informative error message therefore, I assume it is the closest to the correct syntax of all the variations I have tried. Any help with this example and possibly the underlying concept would be greatly appreciated.

```
raise ValueError("`{0}` invalid type for {1} value".format(value, 
self.object_type))
ValueError: `{"columnId": 2068210422966148}` invalid type for <class 
'smartsheet.models.cell_link.CellLink'> value
```

I believe I have found the answer to this question. It seems as though you just need to create a dictionary of the attributes like:

```
ex_dict = {sheet_id: 0974792938, column_id: 07263839242, row_id: 
2632938474839}

new_cell.link_in_from_cell = ex_dict
```

The trick is later in the code. Instead of creating a new row like:

```
row = ss.models.Row()
```

You need to update an existing row like:

```
row = ss.Sheets.get_row(sheet_id, row_id)
```

However, I am still having a weird error of:
    Field \"createdAt\" was of unexpected type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending Row and Cell objects with only the properties that you wish to change. You do *not* want to attempt to modify an existing Row object (e.g. with the `createdAt` property, but rather allocate a new one with appropriate row id and cells to update.

See https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-snippets/blob/04951c2ca8ae1a97386bdd3fa6e010f2845e1421/samples.py#L45 for a complete example of creating a cell link.

Comment: The advice and link you shared will save me a ton of time. Thank you Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, I have followed your sample of creating a cell link object in your script which you linked to above and It is not working for me. I went as far as just replacing the source and destination IDs (row, column and sheet) in your sample code, but I am still getting the same error. "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value." Also, when I try to print cell_link.status, I get a None value back. Is there any chance this script was written for a previous version of the API? Currently, I am running on version 1.3.3. Thanks again for all your help.